# DeprecationWarning: collection.insert is deprecated. Use insertOne, insertMany or bulkWrite instead

Tags: mongodb, ionic-framework, loopback

I'm developing a LoopBack backend for Ionic frontend. It uses MongoDB as a database.

In **package.json**, I've tried to upgrade the dependency `loopback-connector-mongodb` upto `^3.6.0` from `^3.4.1`, but I faced this caution.

> DeprecationWarning: collection.insert is deprecated. Use insertOne,
>   insertMany or bulkWrite instead.

However, I've still found no solution yet so that I guess I've got to downgrade again. (If so, no such caution ¯_(ツ)_/¯ )

Any better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Update your insert methods to use insertOne and so on as advised.

Comment: No worries. There is open github issue [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/455). Looks like downgrade is one option for you or you can keep the newer version  if you dont mind warnings.

Comment: Unless I miss something this has been fixed in 3.7.0 version. See commit https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/commit/b87e617bbef2bb6b400754cef8d70809af10883c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found some github issues below to get convinced that this problem has been fixed for now.

- [DeprecationWarning: collection.insert is deprecated](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3981)
- [Replace deprecated commands](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/pull/461)

Now I've upgraded the version with `^4.2.0` and everything seems to be okay.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of db.insert  write db.insertMany for multiple data inserted
for single data db.insertOne